# responsive background image bootstrap 3 asp.net 4.5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

Hi guys I will really appreciate getting responsive background image solved. I have already gone through over a dozen answers/suggestions on this but it isn't working for me.
My challenge:
without explicitly specifying "height" in pixels, my image will not appear and i think the height affects transition from desktop to mobile. I am using asp.net 4.5 (with master page) and bootstrap 3.0.
Here is my html and css:

```
<div class="container-fluid imgBackground">
</div>
```

`.imgBackground {
    background-image: url('../Images/marine.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 480px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size:100% auto;`

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/THU7IqfrVX